# Debugging CLR Stored Procedure failure - server memory issue? ; Another query caused the AppDomain db.dbo[runtime].4 to be unloaded

Tags: debugging, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-3.5, clrstoredprocedure

I'm using C# .NET 3.5 CLR stored procedures to import data into SQL-Server 2008 R2.
Theoretically.

The job failed with the message:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "RawDataStaging": 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'DN'.
```

It seemed like an error in my code, so I attempted to debug the clr assembly, but the debugging aborts with the following message:

```
.NET Framework execution was aborted. Another query caused the AppDomain db.dbo[runtime].4 to be unloaded
```

Googling around seems to suggest that this is a memory issue, but I can't find a good match for my issue.

**Update:** I've handled the first error, but still can't debug the CLR assembly, which is what this question is about.
The debugging aborts usually around the following code:

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = this._sCsvdePath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = sCommandArguments;

            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            GC.Collect();
```

Most of the time the I can continue stepping through the code until `proc.WaitforExit();` But on some debugging I've made it a few lines past `GC.Collect()`, and I've also once had it aborted at `proc.Start()`. It's not the syntax of the code, because it works the first time I run through it, but when the method is called a second time, the debugging aborts. When I execute the code on the server everything works fine.

Comment: You might need to show some code. I highly doubt that a memory issue would yield an "Incorrect syntax near" error.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I already cleared the first issue - didn't escape the single-quotes in the Insert string, stupid. Nonetheless, I still can't debug the CLR-Assembly, and get the abortion message. I've updated the question with some code.

Comment: Did you find a good solution ?

Comment: @BaptX I switched jobs and now I write JavaScript for WebBrowsers. Easy to debug everything there.

Comment: That's definitely a solution :)